# Python Crawler - html.fromstring

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to parse web page with this code.

```
ac = requests.get('link....')
html_text = ac.text
lx = html.fromstring(html_text)
```

When I run this code I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Crawler.py", line 197, in <module>
cnx.close()
File "Crawler.py", line 46, in RequestPage
lx = html.fromstring(html_text)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 867, in fromstring
doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 752, in document_fromstring
value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:76696)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1830, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115101)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1711, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:113677)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1051, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:107847)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 584, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102150)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 694, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103800)
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102888)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: line 1843: Tag ie:menuitem invalid
```

I found the html tag which cause to the error:

```
<ie:menuitem id="MSOMenu_Help" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/HelpIcon.gif" onmenuclick="MSOWebPartPage_SetNewWindowLocation(MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpLink'), MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpMode'))" text="Help" type="option" style="display:none">

</ie:menuitem>
```

Comment: you'll probably need to define a custom element so lxml can understand the Sharepoint magic: http://lxml.de/element_classes.html

Comment: Or use BeautifulSoup module as an alternative, it knows how  to handle namespaced elements.

Answer (score 0):

You found the HTML tag that case the error but did you fix it? If not try this:

`ac = requests.get('link....')
lx = html.fromstring(ac.content)
valueOfHTMLTag = lx.xpath('//TAG[@class/id="Name"]/text()')`

where you change:

- TAG in the tag that you want to get the value of.
- choose class or id of the tag
- the id/class name of the tag

This will return an array with the values of that tag with the correct class/id.

Hope this helps!